# Typemissmatch in jpa repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use the NamedParameters approach for a query using JpaRepository wuth Spring MVC and I'm getting this error

[image]

I don't understand why I get this error, can someone help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please paste the source code rather than screenshot?

Comment: Which @Param you want to use? org.jboss.logging.Param or org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param ? I think you want to use org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param. Please change the import statement for Param

Comment: Hi @hutingung I already imported the org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param but still don't work

Comment: Can you paste the latest code?